# How can I create a thumbnail based on an fbx file?

Tags: python-2.7, thumbnails, fbx

Using autodesk's fbx sdk and python plugin, it seems it should be possible to create a small jpg as a preview image for an fbx file.
However, I can't figure out how to do it.

Which methods do I need to use/ setup to create a small thumbnail jpg for an fbx file?

In the end, I want a process that allows a user to upload an fbx file, into their library, and show a preview/thumbnail of that file from a web interface.

Comment: Did you manage to obtain a thumbnail? I'm currently visualizing my models with threejs but I want small thumbnails to show as a preview in a list of models. I'm working with React for frontend and Django as backend.

Comment: I always thought about using Blender to generate thumbnails as it's FOSS and has a wide range of supported types but I didn't find the API for that yet (if there is any).